# How to display a result from an excel formula as a percent without changing the cell format to percent or the value format to text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula which calculates % margin between our cost and our sell price, which is ((price-cost)+rebate)/price

I made a LAMBDA formula which spills out a bunch of related calculations into the cells surrounding, but I don't want them to have to change the cell formats when they use this formula.

I know I can adjust the number format for the cell to Percent, but I want this formula to be capable of being used anywhere. I thought about using TEXT(percent,"#,##0.00 %) but I don't want to cause Excel to consider it a text value if they would like to reference the values.

[image]

Are there any other Excel formulas which could provide a decimal as a Percentage which may not convert the value to text?

Comment: I don't think that is possible: either you have a value (which is a number) and use the cell format for the displaying options - or you return a formatted value which then is text due to the %-symbol.

Comment: This is what Excel does to format the data, if you want to do it manually concatenating the information then the result will be a text similar with `TEXT` function. The only way that I can think of is to add another column with the symbol, so you have the number in one cell and the `%` in the next cell.